# How to calculate expected counts in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Observed
391
1346
97
178
340
108
```

I would like to calculate the expected counts for this dataset. For instance, I would ideally like to have something like this:

```
Observed  Expected
391       xxx
1346      xxx
97        xxx
178       xxx
340       xxx
108       xxx
```

The issue I have here is that the range of data is (0, 52208) which is very large. I will provide a histogram of the data down below as well.
[Histogram of Observed Counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVwbv.png)

From the histogram, it looks like this dataset is 0 inflated, but in fact only 58 out of 3,104 observations are 0.

I have tried fitting a modeling a the expected counts by fitting a Poisson and Negative Binomial model, but they both fail the goodness of fit test. Are there any other ways to calculate this?

Comment: Won't the expected count for the variable just be the mean? How do you expect it to vary in the `Expected` column?

Comment: You must make a decision about what distribution makes sense for your data.You tried to fit Poisson and Negative Binomial distributions to the data, but did not show us your code. Why do you think these distributions might be appropriate? The histogram shows that almost all of the values are between 0 and 500. Perhaps plotting on a log scale would make the pattern clearer.